# Is there any easy way to clear up paint 'dribbles'?

Tags: paint, ceramic-tile

This weekend I finished painting the wall tiles in our kitchen - white undercoat then a satin Bordeaux top coat. The next day, I noticed that in one or two places I'd overloaded the roller, and there were unsightly paint runs/drips down a few tiles.

Is there any easy way (other than the obvious 'sand it down and start again') to get rid of them?

It's oil-based paint, if that makes a difference, so it's not completely set hard yet.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I've never been able to find a satisfactory way other than "sand it down and start again".

The only upside is that you should only need to sand down the affected area and repaint that. The paint is new enough that there shouldn't be any difference in the colour and with care you should be able to feather in the patch.

As you are painting over tiles, you might be able to get away without any feathering - just sand all of the affected tile and then when you repaint take care not to touch the adjoining tiles.

Comment: Yeah, the feathering was worrying me a bit. The advantage with tiles is that at worse I can just redo the affected tile.

Comment: @Benjol - you might be able to get away without feathering on tiles.